# I can't use the "ñ" and tildes in python using Visual Studio

Tags: python, visual-studio

When trying to use ñ in python, I get this error:

```
"Welcome_Message = f"Hello {Name} {Last Name} you are {Age} years old"

"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf1 in position 0: unexpected end of data"
```

removing the Ñ fixes this, but I require it for my file.

This is the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


#Definimos las variables.

Nombre = "Esteban"
Apellidos = "Acosta Aponte"
Edad = 18

#Concatenamos colocando f al inicio de la declaración (Todo debe ir dentro del parentesis
# usando las llaves solo las variables)
Mensaje_Bienvenida = f"Hola {Nombre} {Apellidos} tienes {Edad} años"

#Eliminamos datos almacenados en memoria luego de usarlos en mensaje bienvenida
del Nombre
del Apellidos
del Edad

#Imprimimos variable llamada Mensaje_Bienvenida
print(Mensaje_Bienvenida)

#Buscamos que la palabra "Esteban" este en la variable Mensaje_Bienvenida usando in si esta
#devolvera True y si no esta devolvera False
print("Esteban" in Mensaje_Bienvenida)

#Buscamos que la palabra "Pedro" NO este en la variable Mensaje_Bienvenida usando not in si
#no esta devolvera True y si esta devolvera False
print("Pedro" not in Mensaje_Bienvenida)
```

I need to use the ñ and the tildes, I already tried everything, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you saving the source file with UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: Can't reproduce the (UTF-8 encoded) code in your question doesn't raise a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Brian How can I save it as utf-8? I tried it in Visual Studio but I didn't know how, since in Vs Code it was easier.